# Explain the meaning

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

I saw this dialogue in a movie, please anyone tell me what is the meaning of this dialogue:

> "If it was going to have happened it would have happened by now."

Comment: Are you sure that the line wasn't "If it was going to happen, it would have happened by now"?

Comment: i have a screen shot of this dialogue so Yes,  sure.

Comment: Would you have understood it if written as @kaipmdh  has it? Your version - was it from an original script, from subtitles, or a transcription after the event?

Comment: Another way to put it is "If it hasn't happened by now it is never going to happen."